# minimal connectivity test for a pod exposed on service not working in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, curl, networking, containers

I'm using minikube version: v1.25.1, win10, k8s version 1.22

There is 1 node, 2 pods on it: `main` and `front`, 1 service - `svc-main`.

I'm trying to exec into front and call main thru service and see some msg confirming connection is ok.

main.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: main
  name: main
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: main
      image: nginx
      command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
      args: ["while true; do echo date; sleep 2; done"]
```

front.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: front
  name: front
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: front
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - while true; echo date; sleep 2; done
```

service is created like this:

```
k expose pod ngin --name=svc-main --type=ClusterIP --port=80 --target-port=80

k get svc
NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
svc-main     ClusterIP 10.104.26.249   <none>        80:31775/TCP   11m
```

When I try to curl from inside front it says "Could not resolve host: svc-main"

```
 k exec front -it -- sh
 curl svc-main:80
```

or this

```
curl http://svc-main:80

curl 10.104.26.249:80
```

I tried the port 31775, same result. What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are creating a Kubernetes pod using your yaml file, you are overwriting the default Entrypoint and Cmd defined in nginx docker image with your custom command and args:

```yaml
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["while true; do echo date; sleep 2; done"]
```

That's why nginx web server doesn´t work in created pods.
You should remove these lines, delete running pods, and create new pods. After that, you will be able to reach the nginx web page by running

```sh
# curl svc-main
```

within your front pod.

You can read more info about defining a command and arguments for a container in a Pod [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)

And there is a good article about Docker CMD and Entrypoint [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/understanding-dockers-cmd-and-entrypoint-instructions)

Comment: thx, it works, but why indicating port with 'curl svc-main:30010' not working, but curl svc-main working?! everywhere i see the instructions to indicate port...

Comment: this is the only answer that helped me after 3d and countless asking in other chats..

Comment: also could you help me with this one: if there is no service exposing a pod, creating valid network policy will not allow connection to it from another pod?

Comment: Thanks, regarding ports 30010 / 31775, these are not being created using minikube on Linux when applying your kubectl expose ClusterIP command and will not be created in production. So, I think it's specific to minikube on win10.

Comment: In your case, if you delete a service, you will be able to reach your 'main' pod by IP. And you can get the IP addresses of pods using the 'kubectl get pod -o wide' command.